# Safari developer certificate not working on windows 10

Tags: safari, certificate, windows-10, safari-extension

I have installed safari 5.1.7 in windows 10 and want to develop a safari extension. I have imported the PFX/p12 file generated through my apple ID in windows but still i get   **"No Safari Developer Certificate"** in my browser. I have followed all the steps mentioned here : https://www.geocerts.com/support/migrate_iis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to build extension using Safari Extension Builder for windows anymore.Safari Builder Extension fails to recognize the extension signing certificate for Safari 9.0.3 or earlier and in windows Safari 5.1.7 was the last update provided by apple. The only solution is to update your signing system to OS X El Capitan v10.11.4 beta or install Safari 9.1 (available on Mac).
https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/

Comment: why don't you go for any hack to make it out ?